# Substitution rule is not working

Tags: evaluation, xact

I'm trying to replicate the equations of motion of the $4\partial$ST theory in Mathematica as is done in [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2207.13074) as I need to use Mathematica and this package for my thesis. However, I have some trouble substituting some quantity $X$ back in to the equations of motion. This $X$ is defined as
$$ X = -\frac{1}{2} g_{ab}\nabla^a\phi \nabla^b\phi\,. $$
I defined "ruleX" that I think does the job but when I apply this rule to the final equations of motion, it does not substitute $X$ back in. The output of the last line is
$$-\alpha[\phi](\nabla_a\phi)(\nabla^a\phi)(\nabla_b\nabla^b\phi) - 2\alpha[\phi](\nabla^a\phi)(\nabla_b\nabla_a\phi)(\nabla^b\phi) - \frac{3}{4}(\nabla_a\phi)(\nabla^a\phi)(\nabla_b\phi)(\nabla^b\phi)\alpha'[\phi]\,. $$
Clearly, this can substitute back values of $X$. If possible, I want something in the following form as in the linked paper:
$$3\alpha X \Box \phi -2\alpha \nabla^\alpha\phi\nabla\beta\phi\nabla_\alpha\nabla_\beta\phi - 3\alpha'X^2 \, .$$
Someone who can explain why this does not work? It's maybe fair to say that I'm relatively new to Mathematica and the solution can maybe be obvious.

As asked, here is the output of "scalartwo":
$$-\frac{1}{4}(\nabla^a\phi)\left(4\alpha[\phi]((\nabla_a\phi)(\nabla_b\nabla^b\phi) +2 (\nabla_b\nabla_a\phi)(\nabla^b\phi)) +3(\nabla_a\phi)(\nabla_b\phi)(\nabla^b\phi)\alpha'[\phi])\right)\,. $$

**EDIT:**
The rule works when I define

```
rule = MakeRule[{CD[-x1][Phi[]]*CD[x1][Phi[]], -2 X[Phi[]]}, 
  MetricOn -> None]
ruleX2 = CD[-x1_][Phi[]]*CD[x1_][Phi[]] :> -2*X[Phi[]]
scalartwoxAct /. rule
scalartwoxAct /. ruleX2
```

In both cases, the output is
$$2\alpha[\phi]X[\phi](\nabla_a\nabla^a\phi)-2\alpha[\phi](\nabla^a)(\nabla_b\nabla_a\phi)(\nabla^b\phi)+\frac{3}{2}X[\phi](\nabla_a\phi)(\nabla^a\phi)\alpha'[\phi]\,. $$
I'll have to accept that I have to define my rules more specific and I still find it kinda weird that Mathematica does not substitute another factor of $X$ in the last term.

````
<< xAct`xTensor`;
<< xAct`xPert`;

DefManifold[M4, 
  4, {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, m, n, c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, 
   d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6, d7, d8, x1, x2, y1, y2, z1, z2}];
DefMetric[-1, metric[-a, -b], CD, PrintAs -> "g"];
DefMetricPerturbation[metric, metpert, \[Epsilon]];
PrintAs[metpert] ^= "h";
DefTensor[Phi[], M4, PrintAs -> "\[Phi]"];
DefTensorPerturbation[PertPhi[LI[order]], Phi[], M4, 
  PrintAs -> "\[Delta]\[CurlyPhi]"];

XPhix = -(1/2) metric[-x1, -x2] CD[x1][Phi[]]*CD[x2][Phi[]];
XPhiy = -(1/2) metric[-y1, -y2] CD[y1][Phi[]]*CD[y2][Phi[]];

DefScalarFunction[Alpha1, PrintAs -> "\[Alpha]"];
DefScalarFunction[X];
ruleX = -1/2 metric[-x1_, -x2_] CD[x1_][Phi[]]*CD[x2_][Phi[]] :> 
   X[Phi[]];

Ltwo = Sqrt[-Detmetric[]] (Alpha1[Phi[]] * XPhix * XPhiy)
Ltwopert = 
  ToCanonical@ContractMetric@ExpandPerturbation@Perturbation@Ltwo;


scalartwo = (VarD[PertPhi[LI[1]], CD][Ltwopert]/Sqrt[-Detmetric[]] /. 
       delta[-LI[1], LI[1]] -> 1 // ContractMetric // ToCanonical // 
    Simplify);
scalartwoxAct = 
 scalartwo // ToCanonical // RicciToEinstein // ToCanonical // 
     SortCovDs // ToCanonical // FullSimplify // Expand /. ruleX

```
````

Comment: What if you remove the factor `-1/2` on the left of `ruleX` and add the factor `-2` on the right? If you post the expression that you get just before applying `ruleX`, then also people that do not use `xact` can help.

Comment: That doesn't work either and I'll edit my post.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but I meant the Mathematica expression (in Inputform) not the LaTeX expression. Sorry if that was not clear. And I really mean the expression just before `/. ruleX` (not `scalartwo`).

Comment: Btw, you should also put brackets around `scalartwo // ... // Expand` as in `(scalartwo // ... // Expand) /. ruleX`.

Comment: I'm not at a computer with xTensor running just now, but have you tried using `MakeRule` (as described [in the documentation here](http://www.xact.es/Documentation/HTML/HTMLLinks/xTensorDoc.nb_60.html))?  My experience is that you need to use these built-in functions for things like replacements & such (rather than the "native" Mathematica functions) because there's a lot going on "under the hood" with seemingly simple objects in xTensor.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for your ideas. I somehow got it kinda working in both ways. However, I changed the rule with contracted indices and brought the factor $-2$ to the other side. I'll edit my post again.

Comment: Re your "have to accept" it could be as easy as using `//. ruleX2`, see [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceRepeated.html), or `Expand`-ing a bit. To learn about rules and patterns, see [this](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Patterns.html) for example.

Comment: `Expand@scalartwo//.rule` will substitute into `X`, but I didn't got the factor `3`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The OP's method deriving the EOM is a bit old-styled based on `` xAct`xPert ``. Personally I recommend `` xAct`xTras ``, in which the first argument of `VarD` can accept both the matter field and the metric.

I write a sample notebook [eom and stress tensor of 4pST.nb](https://github.com/yuriever/stackexchange-answer/) illustrating the workflow of deriving EOM and stress tensor,

[image]

with explanations like

[image]

and the results match the second lines of (A.3) and (A.4) in [2207.13074](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2207.13074.pdf).

---

Notice that the coefficient of
\begin{equation}
\alpha(\phi) X \square \phi
\end{equation}

in (A.4) of [2207.13074](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2207.13074.pdf) can be a typo, c.f. (7) of [2011.03547](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2011.03547.pdf)

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
E^{(\phi)} & \equiv \square \phi-V^{\prime}(\phi) \\
&+2 \alpha(\phi) X \square \phi-2 \alpha(\phi) \nabla^a \phi \nabla^b \phi \nabla_a \nabla_b \phi \\
&-3 \alpha^{\prime}(\phi) X^2+\beta^{\prime}(\phi) \mathcal{G}=0,
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Comment: Hi, thanks! It works. Just one further question, how would you proceed then to compute the tensorial equations of motion, i.e. varying with respect to the metric? I tried recplacing `VarD[phi[],CD]` by `VarD[metric[a,b]]` but that does not yield the correct equations of motion.

Comment: @Kabouter9 I can reproduce the second line of the formula (A.3) by `VarD[metric[a,b],CD]`. I will add the related codes

Comment: @Kabouter9 I wrote a sample notebook with some explanations.

Comment: Thank you! You have no idea how grateful I am! :-)